# Multiple If Statements VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement

I'm very new to VBA and SQL, and I'm currently building a table to be uploaded to SQL onto Excel and using VBA.
I want to essentially say if column I(Check Market) or J(Check m2) have a value that says #NA then go no further and don't carry out the upload or the rest of the code. I think one of the problems might be I already have an IF loop - which is successful and has no errors associated with it.

This is my code so far

```
'Where Marked sht.Cells(Row,15) = "x" 'FIRST IF LOOP
    If sht.Cells(lRow, 15) = "X" Then

  'If I or J columns say #N/A then DO NOT continue
If IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Value) Then MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check Market'"
If IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Value) Then MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check m2'"
''''At the moment it is the above part that isn't successfully running, it notifies the user of an error but doesn't stop the process.

  'Change blank spaces to be Null
 *******






    sSQL = *******Main part of code goes here******                        




     'execute queries
        ********



  'Put back all the 'null' values to blank
      '''''     




End If 'END OF IF X LOOP
```

Comment: use this : If isError(sht.Cells(lRow, 9)) then   MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check Market'"

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vikas, I did put this in but the code just ran as usual, and didn't do anything about the #N/A it just ignored it. If you look at my edit I just did, will your answer still be relevant?

Comment: I just found this: "Columns("L").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents" which (when adapted) can find errors in cells.

Comment: Try using `sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Value` as this uses the current `Value` of the cell

Comment: These have ensured a MsgBox comes up saying theres been an error, but it doesn't stop the process

Comment: You then need to add `End Sub` to the `If` Statement

Comment: Thanks Jean-Pierre, I knew that - I just was giving an example of my code -- I have a larger script but haven't commented it all in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear if there's a possibility that both columns might have an error but I've provided for that just in case.

```
'If I or J say #N/A then dont proceed with upload.
 If iserror(sht.Cells(lRow, 9).value) and iserror(sht.Cells(lRow, 10).value) Then
     MsgBox "Errors in both Columns"

 ElseIf iserror(sht.Cells(lRow, 9).value) Then
     MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check Market'"

 ElseIf iserror(sht.Cells(lRow, 10).value) Then
     MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check KPI'"

 Else: 'Continue

 End if
```

Comment: These have ensured a MsgBox comes up saying theres been an error, but it doesn't stop the process - any other ideas would be welcomed. Thanks GavinP

Comment: Well the "stopping of the process" depends very much on the rest of your code and it's flow. I would suggest that "the process" should sit within the `else` section which would be normal for control flow.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're looping through rows which is where `lrow` comes from?? Therefore, do you want to stop "the process" for all rows, or just the row that the error relates to? Unfortunately I need more information on how the rest of the code looks to be of effective help

Comment: I know - sorry I cant share the rest of the script - its frustrating! I want to stop the process altogether. As if theres an error with one of the columns it means there must be more later on.

Comment: Ok. So where is your loop? `Exit Sub` should work if placed on the subsequent lines of the warning message boxes.

Comment: Hi GavinP - please see the edit - I've blanked out code in some areas with *** but hopefully it will give you a better idea.

Comment: Not really. As above, `Exit Sub` should work when placed after each of the error `MsgBox` lines. If not, then I'm afraid you're going to have to give me the whole code flow from the sub.

Comment: Put that in place, and it worked, but even when there was no error in any of the cells in still exit-ed the sub. Thanks for your help anyway!!!

Comment: Did you put exit in the else condition as well?

Comment: No, I'm probably doing something really silly that's obvious but just missing it because I've looked at it too long...

Comment: 'If I or J say #N/A then dont proceed with upload.

 If IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Value) And IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Value) Then
     MsgBox "Errors in both Columns"

 ElseIf IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Value) Then
     MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check Market'"
Exit Sub
 ElseIf IsError(sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Value) Then
     MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check m2'"
Exit Sub
 Else: 'Continue

 End If

Comment: That seems to be working now - I went back to an older saved copy and put this in.

Comment: Thanks for all your help GavinP

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to your original Code

```
I(9):Check Market J(10):Check m2 
'If I or J say #N/A then dont proceed with upload.
    If sht.Cells(lRow, 9).Value = "#N/A" Then

        MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check Market'"
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf sht.Cells(lRow, 10).Value = "#N/A" Then

        MsgBox "Error in Column 'Check KPI'"
        Exit Sub

    Else: 'Continue
```

Code for exiting with `MsgBox`

```
Dim response
response = MsgBox("My message here.", vbYesNo, "My Title")
If response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox ("You clicked YES.")
```

Comment: I had tried this before, I get an error about a "Next without For" that I didn't get before. I think this option interrupts the other IF loop I was using.

Comment: Could there be an option of adding in a vbCancel option in a msgbox?

Comment: @user5836742 try `Exit Sub` instead of `End`

Comment: no - this doesn't work either - comes up with a compile error 'Next without For'